# Why does my code keep running even after it reaches the end?

Tags: python, solana

I am having some troubles with my program as when it reaches the end of the third() function, it continues to try to execute transactions. I tried having it return None to break out of the seemly infinite loop that it is in with no success. I am sure that I am missing something very simple here and am guessing it has something to do with the recursion that I used. Thanks for any help that you can provide.

```
import asyncio
import base64
import json
import os
import os.path
import time

import httpcore
import requests
from typing import Awaitable
import solana
import httpx
from rich import print
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.transaction import Transaction

# Notes
# This is meant as a bare bones hello world and as such does not have :
#
# - error handling on http calls
# - checks / retries to ensure solana transactions go through
# - logging - just your basic print statement here. But at least you get the Rich pretty printing variant :)
#
# Libraries used
# - https://www.python-httpx.org/ - cause it's shinier and better than requests
# - https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/
# - https://github.com/Textualize/rich for pretty printing - because it rocks.
# I use poetry to manage dependencies but am not including the project file here for brevity.

# Mint constants
USDC_MINT = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v", 6
SOL_MINT = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112", 9
FAB_MINT = "EdAhkbj5nF9sRM7XN7ewuW8C9XEUMs8P7cnoQ57SYE96", 9
FUSD_MINT = "B7mXkkZgn7abwz1A3HnKkb18Y6y18WcbeSkh1DuLMkee", 8

# This works ok - most of the time
rpc_host = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

filename = r"C:\Users\myname\.config\solana\burner.json"


def get_wallet_keypair(filename: str) -> Keypair:
    """Load a keypair from a filesystem wallet."""

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise Exception(f"Wallet file '{filename}' is not present.")

    with open(filename) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        mid = len(data) // 2
        secret_key = data[:mid]
        secret_bytes = bytes(secret_key)
        keypair = Keypair.from_secret_key(secret_bytes)

        print(f"Public Key is: {keypair.public_key}")
        return keypair


async def get_quote(
        input_mint: str, output_mint: str, amount: int, slippage: int = 0.2):
    url_query = f"https://quote-api.jup.ag/v1/quote?outputMint={output_mint}&inputMint={input_mint}&amount={amount}&slippage={slippage}"
    print(url_query)
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.get(url_query)
        return r.json()


async def get_transaction(route: dict, user_key: str) -> dict:
    swap_url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v1/swap"

    input = {"route": route, "userPublicKey": user_key, "wrapUnwrapSOL": True}
    print(json.dumps(input, indent=2))
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.post(swap_url, json=input,
                              timeout=6.0)  # slightly longer timout as the free rpc server can be a bit laggy
        return r.json()


def send_transaction(payer: Keypair, cc: Client, swap_transaction: str, opts: TxOpts) -> str:
    """ Send a serialized transaction to the RPC node """
    trans = Transaction.deserialize(base64.b64decode(swap_transaction))

    result = cc.send_transaction(trans, payer, opts=opts)
    txid = result["result"]
    print(f"transaction details :https://solscan.io/tx/{txid}")
    return txid


async def async_main(from_mint, from_decimals, to_mint, quantity):
    cc = Client(rpc_host)

    print(f" Converting {quantity} {from_mint} to {to_mint} with {from_decimals} Decimals")

    quote_quantity = quantity * (10 ** from_decimals)
    r = await get_quote(str(from_mint), str(to_mint), quote_quantity, slippage=2)

    quote, outAmount = r["data"][0], int(r['data'][0]['outAmountWithSlippage']) / (10 ** from_decimals)
    print("Out Amount =", outAmount)

    if quote := r["data"][0]:
        print(quote)
    # get the relevant transaction details
    trans = await get_transaction(quote, str(pubkey))

    setup_transaction = trans["setupTransaction"] if "setupTransaction" in trans else None
    swap_transaction = trans["swapTransaction"] if "swapTransaction" in trans else None
    cleanup_transaction = trans["cleanupTransaction"] if "cleanupTransaction" in trans else None

    opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=True)

    # Setup transaction. Will create any missing accounts if required.
    if setup_transaction:
        print("Sending setup transaction")
        #print(setup_transaction)
        send_transaction(payer, cc, setup_transaction, opts)

    # This one actually does the business
    if swap_transaction:
        print("Sending swap transaction")
        txid = send_transaction(payer, cc, swap_transaction, opts)

        # Wait for the transaction to complete before looking it up on chain.
        # Clearly this is *not* the right way to do this. Retry in a loop or something fancy.
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        result = cc.get_transaction(txid, commitment=Confirmed)
        print(result)

    # Haven't seen one of these needed yet. Hopefully the jup.ag devs can explain when it's required.
    if cleanup_transaction:
        print("Sending send transaction")
        send_transaction(payer, cc, cleanup_transaction, opts)
    print("Swap Complete !")
    return outAmount


def get_balance(input_mint):
    url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    if input_mint == "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112":
        data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "getBalance", "params": [f"{pubkey}"]}
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        response = response.text
        parsed = json.loads(response)
        # print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        accountBal = (parsed['result']['value']) / 10 ** SOL_MINT[1]
        print(accountBal)

    else:
        data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
                "params": [f"{pubkey}",
                           {"mint": f"{input_mint}"}, {"encoding": "jsonParsed"}]}
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        response = response.text
        parsed = json.loads(response)
        # print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        accountBal = parsed['result']['value'][0]['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['tokenAmount']['uiAmount']
        print(accountBal)
    return accountBal


# usdc buys fusd fusd is sold for sol sol is sold for usdc

# (from_mint, from_decimals, to_mint, quantity):

class swaps:
    def __init__(self, input_mint, decimals, output_mint, amount):
        self.input_mint = input_mint
        self.decimals = decimals
        self.output_mint = output_mint
        self.amount = amount

    def swap(self):
        asyncio.run(async_main(self.input_mint, self.decimals, self.output_mint, self.amount))


def first(count, previous = 0):
    try:
        if get_balance(USDC_MINT[0]) <= 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            if count >= 60:
                third(0)

            first(count)
    except TypeError:
        first(0)

    step1 = swaps(USDC_MINT[0], USDC_MINT[1], FUSD_MINT[0], get_balance(USDC_MINT[0]) if previous == 0 else previous)
    try:
         step1.swap()
    except httpx.ReadTimeout:
        print("Retrying")
        time.sleep(10)
        first(0)
    second(0)


def second(count, previous = 0):
    try:
        if get_balance(FUSD_MINT[0]) <= 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1

            if count >= 60:
                first(0)
            second(count)
    except TypeError:
        second(0)
    step2 = swaps(FUSD_MINT[0], FUSD_MINT[1], SOL_MINT[0], get_balance(FUSD_MINT[0]) if previous == 0 else previous)
    try:
         step2.swap()
    except:
        print("Retrying")
        time.sleep(10)
        second(0)
    count = 0
    third(0)


def third(count, previous = 0):
    if get_balance(SOL_MINT[0]) < .6:
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1
        if count >= 60:
            second(0)
        third(count)

    step3 = swaps(SOL_MINT[0], SOL_MINT[1], USDC_MINT[0], get_balance(SOL_MINT[0]) - 0.5 if previous == 0 else previous)
    try:
         step3.swap()
    except:
        print("Retrying")
        time.sleep(10)
        third(previous)
    print("All Swaps Completed")
    return None


payer = get_wallet_keypair(filename)
pubkey = payer.public_key
loops = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    previousBalence = get_balance(USDC_MINT[0])
    print(f"Starting Balence: {previousBalence}")
    #for loops in range(5):
    first(0)
    loops += 1
    endBalance = get_balance((USDC_MINT[0]))
    print(f"End balence is {endBalance}")
    totalProfit = endBalance-previousBalence
    print(f"Total Profit is: {totalProfit}")
```

Edit: The output when the code continues is it keeps trying to swap fUSD for SOL and SOL for USDC over and over again.

Solution: https://pastebin.com/8id7gfe4

Comment: This would make sense except the output to the program after it continues is it tries to swap negative solana via Jupiter and even tries to go back to second()

Comment: Add a break point at the first line of `third`, and go in debug line by line. And probably you will see where do you get back to `third` all the time. Then you can figure out why. I was looking at that thing for minutes but I'm lost... You are jumping from everything to everything...

Comment: I did that and it goes back to second() seemingly out of nowhere. And yes sorry for the messy code writing Solana is lets just say... not meant for Python. It made it to the end, printed "All Swaps Complete" and than proceeded to second()

Comment: Btw I think you should check the return value from `third` because even if you finish `third`, you never check it so it is possible that somewhere you just keep running again and again because you ignored the return value from `third` Now that `return None` does nothing as I see...

Comment: I suspect that when you go back to `second()` from `third()` that `second()` resets the counter in `third()` to `0` so it starts all over again

Comment: @DrBwts I will check this but since the transactions are not failing the count is never reaching 100 so this should not be the problem.

Comment: This looks like a recursion problem you are calling third within third without any guard clauses. So if get_balance(SOL_MINT[0]) < .6 you call third and if this time the try is going into the except block you might run into an endless loop. Maybe restructuring the code would help with the problem. Try to make it less complex.

Comment: @Raavgo Hm ok ill look into this its just odd that it makes it to the end of the third() function, prints that its done and than decides to do more. That is where I'm lost

Comment: @ZachFrank Because you absolutely ignore the return from `third`. And if you reach the end of third deeply, it is more likely that some of the previously called `first` or `second` will run for some more cycles, which can lead to a `third` call somewhere and  again and again...
Return some value and check that, indicating that after that every function should simply return and shouldn't do anything anymore...

Comment: @simre is there any way for me to break out of this recursion in ```third()```? The reason that I am using recursion is so that I can easily rerun the transaction when the funds go through. If i take the recursion out it becomes much harder.

Comment: @ZachFrank I'm not sure if I fully understand your code. The problem is that as you goo down the rabbit hole (recursion), you will come back on the same way. So you can't simply exit after third is done. I did some "ugly" code for you, but I think it'll be ok: https://pastebin.com/8id7gfe4  So what I did is returning True at the end of `third`. And this is the only place where a True is returned. And every call is checked. So as soon as you end the third, a True return value will be propagated backward, terminating every previous call in the recursion. Not 100% if it will work...

Comment: @ZachFrank And maybe you can simply write `return first(..)`, `return second(..)`, `return third(..)` everywhere. I'm not sure if you have to continue a function after a "child" is returned or not. Since the only end point is third, and there you should stop everything, so maybe you can simply use return like: https://pastebin.com/aZMNgZYJ
  Sorry, your code is still not 100% clear for me..

Comment: @simre i put you code in in space of mine and it worked. Your a lifesaver I've been trying to fix this for hours. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @ZachFrank Which one did u used? You should use the second one. It is clearer. But in the first one you can return `False` from any function and the previously called function fill be continued, but I'm not sure if it is legit in your code. So go with the second one. On the other hand I think it can be written in a simple infinite loop and it'll be much simpler and much faster (recursion is SLOW, avoid it if you can).. And why do you have a try block? Where can you get a TypeError exception in the try block? Maybe I'm blind but I can't see...